# Could anyone give an **example** that a problem that can be solved by creating a new group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, soft-question

**Motivation**

I was taking a course in abstract algebra. The professor is explaining that we need abstract algebra to convert difficult problems into algebraic way of solving. That's nice, but he started explaining *groups* and then he said we can *make up our own number systems*. I didn't quite understand the essence of creating a new number systems.

**Question**

Could anyone give an **example** that a problem that can be solved by creating a new group?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are there real world applications of finite group theory?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/324253/are-there-real-world-applications-of-finite-group-theory)

Comment: they used groups structures  in chemistry and biology to find symmetry of all positions of atom to make drugs and antibiotics, etc...to find cancer and illness..

Comment: For something to **only** be solvable by inventing new groups is probably difficult. Is it ok with an answer which gives example where a problem becomes easier to solve with group theory?

Comment: @mathreadler, Sir that would be a great help. Actually my Prof. in Complex number analysis explained that by introducing "i" in our number system we can solve any polynomial equation easily and also understanding the Complex plane with polar representation made me think solving problems by visualizing geometry behind several operations and functions. Now suddenly I cant wrap around this new Number systems concept.

Comment: This is only meant to be a partial answer, but as an elementary example of why you want to consider 'other number systems' even to solve the equation 3x=2 (mod 5) in number theory you are already working over a different 'number system' (i.e. the integers modulo 5).

Comment: There is a "magic trick" such that to understand how it works, one lust understand the chinese remainder theorem for groups $\mathbb{Z}/ab\mathbb{Z}$. I don't know if that counts though

Answer (score 1):

In *algebraic topology* groups are used to study *topological spaces*...  But this is more advanced. ..

For example, the spheres   $S ^n $ and $S ^m$ aren't homeomorphic ( topologically the same) for $m\not =n $, because they have different *homology* groups. ..

Answer (score 0):

The Pell equation is the equation $x^2-dy^2 = 1$  where $d$ is a positive
non-square integer. The set of all solutions of the Pell equation is
infinite. The first solution $(x_1, y_1)$ of the Pell equation is called the
fundamental solution.

One may rewrite the Pell equation as $x^2-dy^2=(x+y\sqrt d)(x-y\sqrt d)=1$

so that finding a solution comes down to finding a nontrivial unit
in the ring $\mathbb Z[\sqrt d]$. This reformulation implies
that once one knows a solution, fundamental solution, of the Pell
equation, one can find infinitely many others. More precisely, if the
solutions are ordered by magnitude, then the $ n th$ solution $(x_n, y_n)$
can be expressed in terms of the fundamental solution by

$x_n+y_n \sqrt d=(x_1+y_1\sqrt d)^n$ for $n >1$