# What is the real life application of group theory other than coding and cryptography

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, applications

What is the real life application of group theory other than coding and cryptography if any and how can one apply group theory to them.

Comment: One often used place is to model symmetric relationships. This is often used together with group actions, for example.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/324253/are-there-real-world-applications-of-finite-group-theory?rq=1).

Comment: My question is: is there a real-life application of live homo sapiens outside of coding?

Comment: Search by Group Theory applied to Chemistry and Fisics. I can't give you a complete answer because I'm a graduate student on Group Theory but I don't develop research on applied Group Theory. I hope this helps.

Comment: Quantum physics uses groups. Eg, QCD uses SU(3), see https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/108641/123208

Comment: @MoisheKohan Well, not all groups are finite...

Comment: @user1729: Of course, but in this case OP needs to clarify that they are interested in infinite groups. Incidentally, there is a story about Conway and how all groups are finite! See [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/45016/an-anecdote-by-r-schmidt).

Comment: Three-dimensional space groups are important in crystallography. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_group

Answer (score 4):

[Braid groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braid_group) are a class of (infinite) groups whose nice geometric description lends themselves to some interesting applications, such as:

1. Designing stirring rods [[1](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1204.6730.pdf), [2](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1208.0785.pdf)], which has applications in medicine (automatically stirring constituent (viscose) parts of a medicine).
2. Pulling taffy [[3](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1608.00152.pdf)]. In particular, analysing taffy pullers and making better ones. (The paper does not explicitly mention braid groups, but it is what is going on in the background.)